# Check installed grub2 modules

Tags: centos, grub2

I run CentOS 7. Is there a way (e.g., a command) to check which grub2 modules are currently installed?

Comment: grub?  something like `rpm -qa` or `rpm -qa grub*` ?

Answer (score 2):

Grub2 comes in two flavours. UEFI and *old style PC BIOS systems*. The question *installed modules* can either refer to the modules provided by the RPM package(s), or the modules installed by grub on the disk.

Grub packages. My system is a *PC BIOS system*, so `grub2` is installed. (`grub2-efi*` would be installed on an UEFI system).

```
$ yum list 'grub2*'
Installed Packages
grub2.x86_64               1:2.02-0.16.el7.centos          base     
grub2-tools.x86_64         1:2.02-0.16.el7.centos          base     
Available Packages
grub2-efi.x86_64           1:2.02-0.16.el7.centos          base     
grub2-efi-modules.x86_64   1:2.02-0.16.el7.centos          base
```

### Packages installed by RPM package

You can list the GRUB2 modules installed (provided by the RPM package), that could be installed on your /boot or EFI partition. (I used `| head -n5` for smaller example):

```
$ find  /usr/lib/grub/ -name "*.module"
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/cs5536.module
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/acpi.module
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/date.module
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/adler32.module
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/datehook.module
```

### Packages installed by RPM package

You can list the GRUB2 modules installed (provided by the RPM package), that could be installed on your /boot or EFI partition (again, I used `| head -n5` for smaller example):

```
$ find /boot/grub2/i386-pc -name "*.mod" | head -n5
/boot/grub2/i386-pc/acpi.mod
/boot/grub2/i386-pc/date.mod
/boot/grub2/i386-pc/adler32.mod
/boot/grub2/i386-pc/datehook.mod
/boot/grub2/i386-pc/affs.mod
```

### List of modules embedded in `grubx64.efi` and `gcdx64.efi`

According to [grub2.spec](https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!grub2/c695181b7bb165516116ba7c7d94805c799ae977/SPECS!grub2.spec#L345), those EFI boot files contains the following modules:

```
GRUB_MODULES="    all_video boot btrfs cat chain configfile echo efifwsetup \
   efinet ext2 fat font gfxmenu gfxterm gzio halt hfsplus iso9660 \
   jpeg loadenv lvm mdraid09 mdraid1x minicmd normal part_apple \
   part_msdos part_gpt password_pbkdf2 png reboot search \
   search_fs_uuid search_fs_file search_label sleep syslinuxcfg \
   test tftp regexp video xfs"
%ifarch aarch64
GRUB_MODULES="${GRUB_MODULES} linux"
%else
GRUB_MODULES="${GRUB_MODULES} linuxefi multiboot2 multiboot"
%endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an `rpm` command - either `rpm -qa | grep grub` to list all packages with the string "grub" in the package name, or `rpm -ql grub` to list all files that come as part of the payload of the `grub` package.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that the question is not clear in itself.

Heading talks about "grub" while the question details does not talk anything about grub.

So, I assume that you may be asking for either of the two things :

- grub modules/files --> use "rpm -ql grub" command to list all the files provided by grub
- all the module (driver/kernel) --> use "lsmod" command to list all the loaded kernel/driver modules